# How to open this .net project with no errors

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I have this project from github, database on sales and inventory system. But when I open it, it encounters errors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I really need help on how to open this project with no errors? What should I do to fix this project?

PS: Need a step by step explanation regarding this, I just started databases, so I'm not sure what other tools I should be needing like MS Access or SQL.

Comment: Take a look at the references and you will presumably see one for the Microsoft Report Viewer that is flagged as missing.  Whoever created that project probably had it installed on their system.  You can also download and install it or you should be able to add it to the project as a NuGet package.

Comment: Please provide the errors shown.

Comment: So, what I should be doing is to check in the NuGet package? So, here's the thing, what should I search for it? I'm just not that familiar with it, if you don't mind, can you state the reference I should be searching? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory: underlined data types cannot be found.
That's means these types are defined in assemblies, currently not available to the compiler.

So in order to build the solution you need to supply these assemblies. There are multiple options, but I'd recommend doing this through NuGet as it is fully automated(you know about it, right?). 
The missing assembly is related to the `Microsoft.Reporting`. So install this and try to build again.

Comment: Question, do I still need to install any other programs such as sql express something? And on the left side of the picture, it states that the "Azure" is not connected, how can I connect it? 

And one last thing, where can I open the database file?

Comment: Yes, you do need a SQL server; if there isn't one already at your disposal you can install SQL Express. Then you need to specify the server instance in your connection string.

Comment: I guess not but I'm not sure. Is there a provider for .NET? Is there a database already spread for this project? If yes, probably it requires a specific DB engine ... Just run the SQL Express setup and modify the connection string. I guess it is easier than setting up JDBC drivers and ODBC connections.

Comment: Can you try opening the github source code? I've tried in the NuGet package, but I can't seem to find the microsoft.windows.reportviewer. Upon trying to experiment on how to fix this one, I encountered many errors now.